# Can't get emulator x86 images for Android Q. Says "unable to resolve dependencies"

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio is up to date, like everything on the system, yet when I do try to download the Android Q preview on Android Studio, it keeps saying "partially installed".

If you select one by one the packages for the images, the error is "Unable to resolve dependencies"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: you asked and answered at the same time.. so quickly..? what's the point?

Comment: sharing knowledge

Comment: @Sam. there's absolutely nothing wrong with self-answering, assuming both the question and answer is written correctly, and the question is [on-topic](/help/how-to-ask). See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - while SO is intended to share knowledge, there's no requirement or policy stating *you* can't both ask and answer to share something useful.

Comment: @Zoe i did't said anything about it.. it is fine.. but he answered the question as soon as he posted the question.. so the point was to answer the self question. .. even a researching would take at least few minutes.. that is what i was telling.

Comment: @Sam. yes, and that's fine. But when you ask what the point of asking a question is entirely because it's self-answered, that makes it seem like you don't know self-answering is allowed. And there's also a box that lets you post a question and answer at the same time - SE faciliates for these kind of posts. So yes, if you have a problem and already know the answer, you can actually ask and answer both at once, and that's not a problem

Comment: @Sam. when asking the question, there is a button to directly answer. It's meant for case like this one: I already found the solution, tested and validated, then, because I remembered I had not found anything on SO, I thought I should share.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierDybman thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so found the reason why: 
 - you just need the latest Canary version of Android Studio and not the stable one.

Thanks Google for the clarity ;) (not)